# Menu/Topbar changes on scroll up/down

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I've searched all over but can not find a solution where the menu choices of a website changes when a user scrolls down. Does anybody know how to do this (preferably in Foundation)?

Comment: too broad; be more specific: change what? what have you tried so far?

Comment: the menu choices changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad - you may want to explain what you want. I think however you might be looking for a 'sticky' header effect, such as this: http://themenectar.com/demo/salient/ ?

If this is the case, this post ( http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/18987-sticky-header-effect ) on the Foundation forums mentions you can use the class 'sticky' to achieve the same effect.

> In Foundation the same effect can be achieved by wrapping the navbar in a div class="sticky".
>
> As soon as an element with the "sticky" class hits the top of the viewport it gets the class "fixed", which takes care of the positioning. You can also use this class to resize the "stuck" navbar etc.

Comment: Yes something like that only that the menu changes as well, maybe more or less menu choices once user scrolls down.

Comment: Unless you wanted a jquery option, you could have a hidden div with your second menu in it, and have that div show when the 'shrink' class is invoked.

i.e. 

   `.small-nav .menu2 { display: block };`

Where 'small-nav' is whatever class the template is adding to the header to make it shrink. (Edits: hitting enter early)